# How to generate a graph html widget for apriori rules visulization within rmarkdown compiler with a for loop with R?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, r-markdown, apriori

I've been trying to generate a sequence of graph plots inside rmarkdown html compiler...

````
```{r, include=T, echo=F, fig.height=4, fig.width=10,warning=FALSE}
````

Here direct is the directory where the files are listed from

"files" is the list of files objects in the transaction form needed for the read.transaction function argument

````
direct <- "......"
files <- list.files(path = ".....")
 for (i in 1:length(files)) {

    tr<-read.transactions(file = paste(as.character(direct),"/",files[i],sep = ""),format = "basket",sep = ",")

    rules <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(supp=sup, conf=confid))
    rules <- sort(rules, by='count', decreasing = TRUE)

    plotr <- plot(rules, method = "graph",  engine = "htmlwidget")


  }


```
````

I have tried print(plotr), printing just plot(rules,...) and nothing seems to work.

The problem is when I knit the markdown, the plot of the different transaction files doesn't pop up in the html generated by the .Rmd file. Consider that this loop is inside a function that runs inside the chunk.

It would be nice if someone could help me try to solve this problem. If its worth for something, I am trying to generate a report that returns different plot rules based on the apriori algorithm applied to the different files.

If anyone has any idea how this could be solved would be a great help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put multiple htmlWidgets in one RMarkdown chunk you need to create a taglist. Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Example RMarkdown with multiple arulesViz htmlWidgets in one chunk"
output: html_document
---


```{r}
library(arulesViz)

data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.8))

widget_list <- lapply(1:10, FUN = function(i) 
    plot(sample(rules, size = 10), method = "graph", engine = "htmlwidget"))

htmltools::tagList(widget_list)  
```
````

You can also use a regular loop to populate the list. More information on this issue can be found at https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/67

To hide the messages from `library` and `apriori` in the resulting document you can do this:

````
---
title: "Example RMarkdown with multiple arulesViz htmlWidgets in one chunk"
output: html_document
---


<!-- Hide the messages for library -->
```{r, echo = FALSE, results = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(arulesViz)
```

<!-- verbose = FALSE hides the progress report for apriori -->
```{r}
library(arulesViz)
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.001, confidence=0.8), 
  control = list(verbose = FALSE))

widget_list <- lapply(1:10, FUN = function(i) 
    plot(sample(rules, size = 10), method = "graph", engine = "htmlwidget"))

htmltools::tagList(widget_list)  
```
````

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid printing: "## Apriori
## 
## Parameter specification:
##  confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport maxtime support minlen
##         0.8    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE       5   0.001      1
##  maxlen target   ext
##      10  rules FALSE
## 
## Algorithmic control:..." all this part of the code that apriori produces?

Comment: @ArielHiramGómezLópez I have added an example that creates a clean document without messages and warnings.